# when doing global replace in javascript should I do /\%/g or /%/g

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace all the occurrences of character `%` and `_`.

Say `var inputStr = '_temp_temp2%temp3';`
I can replace it by `var replacedStr = inputStr.replace(/_/g, '\\_').replace(/%/g, '\\%');`

And this also gives me the same result `var replacedStr = inputStr.replace(/\_/g, '\\_').replace(/\%/g, '\\%');`

What is the difference between these two? Is there any significance of putting that extra `\` in second case? Currently I am getting same output for both the cases, is there any risk of using the first method i.e. without the escape caharacter `\`? I have tried to understand from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), but didn't understand it properly.

Comment: *single slash* works as an escape character only if the resulting string after prepending `\\` also has a special meaning, otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew - I have gone through the answers that you have marked as duplicate. But that doesn't give me the answer for this particular case(or I am not understanding). My simple question is what is the difference if I don't escape the special character because I'm getting the same output for both. Is there any risk of using the first approach?

Comment: Never escape characters that do not have to be escaped - this is the only safe approach. `_` is a **word**, not a special char, it should never be escped. `%` is not a special regex operator and thus should never be escaped.

Comment: Thanks. So, does that mean that though it's giving the same result, 2nd approach is not safe! I should not escape `%` and `_` in Javascript and use the first approach.